# Can't query names from a table that does not exist in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I have two tables that are identical in fields. I want to query names in `table2` that are not in `table1`. Both tables have `name` field as unique (primary key).

Here are the info. of my database design:
My query is:

```
SELECT `table2`.`name` FROM `mydatabase`.`table2`, `mydatabase`.`table1` 
WHERE `table2`.`name` NOT IN (SELECT  `table1`.`name` FROM `mydatabase`.`table1`)
AND table2`.`name` NOT LIKE 'xyz%';
```

The output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table name>:`

For `table1`:

```
table1, CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `name` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `grade` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `extended_ip` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`),
  UNIQUE KEY `mydatabase_name_UNIQUE` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And `table2`:

```
tabl2, CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `name` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `grade` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `extended_ip` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`),
  UNIQUE KEY `mydatabase_name_UNIQUE` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

`The output of EXPLAIN <my query>`:

```
# id, select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
1, PRIMARY, table1, , index, , mydatabase_name_UNIQUE, 502, , 17584, 100.00, Using index
1, PRIMARY, table2, , index, , mydatabase_name_UNIQUE, 502, , 46264, 100.00, Using where; Using index; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
2, SUBQUERY, table1 , index, PRIMARY,mydatabase_name_UNIQUE, mydatabase_name_UNIQUE, 502, , 17584, 100.00, Using index
```

**EDIT:**
And I forgot to mention what happens is that the databse just crashes with my query. i am using `mysql-workbench` in `Ubuntu 18`. When I perform this query the whole workbench closes and I have to restart opening it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a [LEFT JOIN](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-left-join.aspx) on `name`, with `table2` as your starting table, since you want to consider **all the** names from `table2` which do not exist in `table1`. Names which don't exist in `table1` will have a `null` value post the join. Note that this join based solution will be significantly faster than any subquery based approach.

Also, you should avoid **comma (,)** based implicit joins. It is old syntax, and you should use explicit `JOIN` based syntax. Read: [Explicit vs implicit SQL joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins)

Also, it is a good habit to use [Aliasing](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/) for better readability

Try the following:

```
SELECT t2.name 
FROM `mydatabase`.`table2` AS t2
LEFT JOIN `mydatabase`.`table1` AS t1 ON t1.name = t2.name 
WHERE t1.name IS NULL 
  AND t2.name NOT LIKE 'xyz%';
```

Comment: This works, too, and may be more efficient than using a subquery :)

Answer (score 0):

Try a subquery:

```
SELECT `table2`.`name` FROM `mydatabase`.`table2` WHERE `table2`.`name` NOT IN (SELECT `table1`.`name` FROM `mydatabase`.`table1`);
```

Comment: What about the rest of my query (I also have LIKE statement). can you complete your query please?

Comment: Also, I'm already using subquery like yours if you see my query.

Comment: If your goal is simply to query names in table2 that are not in table1 then my answer is what you want.  Having both tables in the From is giving you problems.  If you have additional criteria for table2.name then you can put it in a WHERE after the subquery: AND table2`.`name` NOT LIKE 'xyz%';

Comment: THanks for selecting my answer however please also consider the answer from @Madhur Bhaiya. In many cases it will be more efficient to LEFT JOIN and check for IS NULL.